# I'd like to add a table style, like the ones that appear in the tinyMCE style combo box, not the table properties box

Tags: tinymce, plone

When you go through the choices for the tinyMCE "style..." combo box, there is a section for styling tables, cells and rows. How can I add another of these?

It doesn't seem to match up with the options in TinyMCE settings -> styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one new row in the `Styles` section. 
For example:

```
Special Row|tr|MySpecialCSSKlass
```

Of course you have to style `MySpecialCSSKlass` by your own. 
You have to **reset the JS cache** before this change take effect.

It's also necessary to place the curser inside of table row/cell.
[image]

Comment: What makes it appear under the table subheading? Is it because the tag is 'tr'?

Comment: Yes, it's because of the tag.